# Projectile project in folder without write access?

Tags: projectile

At times I want to browse the code of projects to which I have read-only access.  This makes it impossible for me to drop a `.projectile` file at the root of the project.

Is there a way to define projects for use with projectile when I do not have write access to the project directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub user thomasf [provided a workaround](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/364#issuecomment-61296248) which I modified only slightly:

```
;; (source: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/364#issuecomment-61296248)
(defun projectile-root-child-of (dir &optional list)
  (projectile-locate-dominating-file
   dir
   (lambda (dir)
     (--first
      (if (and
           (s-equals? (file-remote-p it) (file-remote-p dir))
           (string-match-p (expand-file-name it) (expand-file-name dir)))
          dir)
      (or list project-root-regexps (list))))))

(defvar project-root-regexps ()
  "List of regexps to match against when projectile is searching
  for project root directories.")

(add-to-list 'project-root-regexps "/path/to/some/project/$")
(add-to-list 'project-root-regexps "/path/to/another/project/$")
(add-to-list 'project-root-regexps "/path/to/one/more/project/$")

(nconc projectile-project-root-files-functions '(projectile-root-child-of))
```

This lets me add projects to to the list `project-root-regexps`, and as far as I can tell they behave just as if they had a `.projectile` file at their root.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you can temporary disable `projectile-require-project-root`:

```
(setq projectile-require-project-root nil)
```

Then, you can activate Projectile everywhere.

Comment: I just tried this out, and it seems like it would only be useful in a flat directory structure.  As soon as I open a file in `src/` the project root changes to `src/` and I can no longer jump to the files in `inc/`.

Comment: There's no way to interactively add to project list. But you may try manually adding a directory to `projectile-known-projects`. You could also look at this [issue](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/364). Probably you should update the issue, so someone could add this feature.

Comment: Adding to `projectile-known-projects` suffered from the same subdirectory issue that I mentioned in my first comment.  I did add a comment to the GitHub issue though, and I got a helpful response.